# Google directory api always returns 403

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I am trying to use the Admin SDK Directory api to look up user profiles. I am able to do this successfully all day (with in quota) with 99% of the time. Though there are certain times where it just fails no matter what.

Yes I have set the service account user, I have the proper scopes, I have admin api turned on.

It even fails in the google api explorer. See screen shots

The call:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9v9m6s5zf76oix7/call.png?dl=0

The response:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/te6k3x5xjkr467j/response.png?dl=0

Sorry for the links, images keep showing as broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting google they supplied an answer. There is a setting for the contacts app that enables and disables this.

Admin console >> Google Apps >> Settings for Contacts >> Advanced settings

Contact sharing: Enable contact sharing

Make sure that is enabled and it works.

Here is a screen shot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8jmzz7zw0xq4ux4/answer.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it just seems like some sort of transient error on the Google side. Being that it's working ~99% of the time for you, means you're not doing anything wrong. I would consider this more true b/c you're also using a Google Tool rather than your own so you know it's not the code. When it's failing for you, does it also then fail with the API explorer? What about with the OAuth Playground?

If this is reproducible consistently (same times, after X amount of requests, etc.), it would be worth reporting the the Google for Work Support team (assuming you have the ability to contact support) as it sounds like a bug and they would be able to help with break/fix for API issues.

Comment: Yea, I was hoping someone had an idea, but I feel it'll come to that.